# Using project katana what is the correct way to specify the startup class in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, katana

One of the ways of specifying the Startup class in Katana is through the owin:AppStartup key in appSettings in web.config

> If the web.config file contains an appSetting with
>   key=“owin:AppStartup”, the loader uses the setting value. The value
>   must be a valid .NET-type name.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx

This is my web.config's app.settings:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyStartup, MyAssemblyName"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Unfortunately I get this error:
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- For the app startup parameter value 'MyStartup, MyAssemblyName', the class 'MyStartup' was not found in assembly 'MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

(I've tried with the fully qualified name, MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, and I get the same error)

If I use the alternative of specifying the app startup class in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
using MyAssemblyName;
...
[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(MyStartup))]
```

It works without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're missing a namespace:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyAssemblyName.MyStartup, MyAssemblyName"/>
  </appSettings>
```